# Spurious lines when scrolling a GDI+ object

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I am following a [GDI+ tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1355/Professional-C-Graphics-with-GDI), and in the section Drawing Shapes and Lines there's a simple example that draws a filled rectangle, filled ellipse and filled line in a scrolling window. It seems to work fine, but when I scroll down and back up it doesn't scroll properly as shown: [image]

The `OnPaint` method is:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics dc = e.Graphics;
        Point ScrollOffset = this.AutoScrollPosition;
        dc.TranslateTransform(ScrollOffset.X, ScrollOffset.Y);
        if (e.ClipRectangle.Top + ScrollOffset.X < 350 || 
            e.ClipRectangle.Left + ScrollOffset.Y < 250)
        {
            dc.DrawRectangle(BluePen, rectangleBounds);
            dc.FillRectangle(CrossBrush, rectangleBounds);
            dc.DrawEllipse(RedPen, ellipseBounds);
            dc.FillEllipse(SolidAzureBrush, ellipseBounds);
            dc.DrawLine(BrickWidePen, rectangleBounds.Location, ellipseBounds.Location + ellipseBounds.Size);
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

(The rest of the code can be seen at the page linked above, in case it matters).

If I minimise and restore it fixes the problem, so it looks as if the OnPaint method isn't getting called at the right time (is the window being scrolled between the `OnPaint` method being called and the paint actually occurring?). So how *should* I handle the paint so the scrolling doesn't corrupt the image?

Comment: `e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);`  Then redraw everything, so eliminate your if-condition.  Make sure you have `this.DoubleBuffered = true;` in the form's constructor.

Comment: It should be sufficient to just eliminate the `if`. The invalidation of the window that causes the `WM_PAINT` message in the first place (which in turn causes `OnPaint()` to be called) will normally cause the background to be refreshed as well, clearing the area that is to be redrawn. Of course, without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what is needed to fix the problem. Please improve the question if you still cannot get it to work. (And no, a link to some other page full of code does not a good [mcve] make).